# My isset function is not working correctly

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have made a registration form using jquery and php which dynamically checks the data that the user enters.

When I click the button nothing gets sent to the database, I know the query works because when I remove the isset function, blank data does get sent to the database.

Any help would be most appreciated.

html

```
<DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <title>jQuery Tutorial</title>
</head>

<body>
<form>
<input type="text" id="fname" size ="25" placeholder="firstname" />
<span id="fname_feedback"></span></br></br>
<input type="text" id="lname" size ="25" placeholder="lastname" />
<span id="lname_feedback"></span></br></br>
<input type="text" id="username" size ="25" placeholder="username"/>
<span id="username_feedback"></span></br></br>
<input type="text" id="email" size ="25" placeholder="email"/>
<span id="email_feedback"></span></br></br>
<input type="text" id="confirm_email" size ="25" placeholder="confirm email"/>
<span id="confirm_email_feedback"></span></br></br>
<input type="text" id="password" size ="25" placeholder="password"/>
<span id="password_feedback"></span></br></br>
<input type="text" id="confirm_password" size ="25" placeholder="confirm password"/>
<span id="confirm_password_feedback"></span></br></br>
<input type="submit" id="reg" name="reg" value="sign up">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/reg.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

jquery

```
function validate(fname, lname, username, email, confirm_email, password, confirm_password){
$.post('php/registration.php', {
    fname: fname, 
    lname: lname, 
    username: username, 
    email: email,
  confirm_email: confirm_email,
  password: password,
  confirm_password: confirm_password,
  }, 
    function(data){

        $('#fname_feedback').text(data.fname);
        $('#lname_feedback').text(data.lname);
        $('#username_feedback').text(data.username);
        $('#email_feedback').text(data.email);
        $('#confirm_email_feedback').text(data.confirm_email);
        $('#password_feedback').text(data.password);
        $('#confirm_password_feedback').text(data.confirm_password);

    },'json');
}
/////////////////////////////////fname jquery///////////////////////////////////
$('#fname').focusin(function(){ 
  if($('#fname').val() ==='') {
$('#fname_feedback').text('requried field');
} else {

validate($('#fname').val(), "","","","","","");

}
}).blur(function() { 


validate($('#fname').val(), "","","","","","");

}).keyup(function(){

validate($('#fname').val(), "","","","","","");
});
/////////////////////////////////lname jquery///////////////////////////////////
$('#lname').focusin(function(){ 
  if($('#lname').val() ==='') {
$('#lname_feedback').text('requried field');
} else {
validate("", $('#lname').val(),"","","","","");

}
}).blur(function() { 

validate("", $('#lname').val(),"","","","","");


}).keyup(function(){

validate("", $('#lname').val(),"","","","","");


});

/////////////////////////////////username jquery///////////////////////////////////

$('#username').focusin(function(){ 
  if($('#username').val() ==='') {
$('#username_feedback').text('requried field');
} else {
validate("","", $('#username').val(),"","","","");

}
}).blur(function() { 

$('#username_feedback').text('');

validate("","", $('#username').val(),"","","","");


}).keyup(function(){
validate("","", $('#username').val(),"","","","");


});

/////////////////////////////////email jquery///////////////////////////////////

$('#email').focusin(function(){ 
  if($('#email').val() ==='') {
$('#email_feedback').text('requried field');
} else {

validate("","","", $('#email').val(),"","","");

}
}).blur(function() { 

$('#email_feedback').text('');
validate("","","", $('#email').val(),"","","");

}).keyup(function(){
validate("","","", $('#email').val(),"","","");


});

/////////////////////////////////confirm email jquery///////////////////////////////////

$('#confirm_email').focusin(function(){ 
  if($('#confirm_email').val() ==='') {
$('#confirm_email_feedback').text('requried field');
} else {

validate("","","",$('#email').val(), $('#confirm_email').val(),"","");

}
}).blur(function() { 

$('#confirm_email_feedback').text('');
validate("","","",$('#email').val(), $('#confirm_email').val(),"","");
}).keyup(function(){
validate("","","",$('#email').val(), $('#confirm_email').val(),"","");

});


/////////////////////////////////password jquery///////////////////////////////////

$('#password').focusin(function(){ 
  if($('#password').val() ==='') {
$('#password_feedback').text('requried field');
} else {

validate("","","","","", $('#password').val(),"");;

}
}).blur(function() { 

$('#password_feedback').text('');

validate("","","","","", $('#password').val(),"");
}).keyup(function(){
validate("","","","","", $('#password').val(),"");

});

///////////////////////////////// confirm password jquery///////////////////////////////////

$('#confirm_password').focusin(function(){ 
  if($('#confirm_password').val() ==='') {
$('#confirm_password_feedback').text('requried field');
} else {

validate("","","","","",$('#password').val(), $('#confirm_password').val());

}
}).blur(function() { 

$('#confirm_password_feedback').text('');
validate("","","","","",$('#password').val(),  $('#confirm_password').val());
}).keyup(function(){
validate("","","","","",$('#password').val(), $('#confirm_password').val());

});


$( "#reg" ).click(function() {
  alert( "form submitted." );
});
```

php

```
 <?php
require '../init.php';
$fname_error= '';
$lname_error='';
$username_error='';
$email_error='';
$confirm_email_error='';
$password_error='';
$confirm_password_error='';
$d = date("Y-m-d"); // Year - Month - Day
if( isset($_POST['fname']) && $_POST['fname'] !== "")
{
    $fname = $_POST['fname'];
    $fname = trim($fname);

   if(strlen($fname) < 5 || strlen($fname) > 15) {

   $fname_error = 'min characters is 5 max 15';

   } else {
    $fname_error= '';
 } 
}

if( isset($_POST['lname']) && $_POST['lname'] !== "")
{
    $lname = $_POST['lname'];
    $lname = trim($lname);

if(strlen($lname) < 5 || strlen($lname) > 20) {

$lname_error = 'min characters is 5 max 20';

  } else  {

$lname_error = '';
  }
}

if(isset($_POST['username']) && $_POST['username'] !== ""){
$username = $_POST['username'];
$username = trim($username);
$u_check = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT username FROM users WHERE username='$username'");
// Count the amount of rows where username = $username
$check = mysqli_num_rows($u_check);

if ($check == 0) {

  if(strlen($username) < 5 || strlen($username) > 20) {

    $username_error = 'username has to be between 5 and 20 characters';
  } else {
    $username_error='';
  }
} else {
     $username_error = 'username taken';
}
}

if(isset($_POST['email']) && $_POST['email'] !== ""){

$email = $_POST['email'];
$email = trim($email);

//Check whether Email already exists in the database
$email_check = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT email FROM users WHERE email='$email'");
//Count the number of rows returned
$email_result = mysqli_num_rows($email_check);

if ($email_result == 0) {

$email_error ='';

 } else {
    $email_error = 'email taken';
 }
}



if(isset($_POST['confirm_email']) && $_POST['confirm_email'] !== ""){

$confirm_email = $_POST['confirm_email'];
$confirm_email = trim($confirm_email);

if ($confirm_email == $email) {
$confirm_email_error ='';

} else {
$confirm_email_error ='nope';

 }
}


if(isset($_POST['password']) && $_POST['password'] !== ""){

$password = $_POST['password'];
$password = trim($password);
if (strlen($password)>30||strlen($password)<5) {
$password_error = "Your password must be between 5 and 30 characters long!";
 } else {
  $password_error ='';
 }
}

if(isset($_POST['confirm_password']) && $_POST['confirm_password'] !== ""){

$confirm_password = $_POST['confirm_password'];
$confirm_password= trim($confirm_password);

if ($password == $confirm_password) {
$confirm_password_error ='';
$password = md5($password);
} else {
$confirm_password_error ='nope';

 }

}


  $query = mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO users(first_name, last_name,username,email,password) VALUES ('', '$fname', '$lname', '$username', '$email', '$password', '$d', '0','','','')");




$return_data=array('fname'=> $fname_error, 'lname'=>$lname_error, 'username'=> $username_error,'email'=>$email_error,'confirm_email'=>$confirm_email_error, 'password'=> $password_error, 'confirm_password'=>$confirm_password_error);

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($return_data);
exit();
?>
```

Comment: please post your full code!!

Comment: I think you got confused. There is not any ajax call to a webpage so there is not a possibility to have this working without an ajax call.

Comment: iv posted my full code

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `name attribute` to your input type's

```
<input type="button" id="reg" name="reg" value="sign up">
```

And your insert query is wrong it would be

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3,...)
VALUES (value1, value2, value3,...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `input` needs a `name`-attribute in order for it to be fetched with `POST`/`GET`.

```
<input type="button" id="reg" name="reg" value="sign up">
```

---

From comments: If you are trying to use this button to submit a form, it needs to be of `type=submit`, like this.

```
<input type="submit" id="reg" name="reg" value="sign up">
```

Comment: i though as long as it had a value attribute it worked

Comment: It works in terms of HTML, but to fetch it with PHP you need to address it by the `name`-attribute.

Comment: the button is still not being set and iv added the above code

Comment: Is this the button that submits the form?

Comment: yeah it submits the form

Comment: Then it needs to be of `type="submit"`, not a `type="button"`. The `name`-attribute is still required for it to be fetched in PHP.